# Vuejs Hide/Show Elements refreshes when Routes change

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, show-hide

I have been developing a Vue project and something caught my attention today. I used checkboxes with some sytling (I use them as toggle switches) throughout the project and thanks to these elements, I show or hide some elements and components. Toggle elements control specific data within each component. When the data istrue, some elements are displayed on the page and when false, they are hidden. What I noticed today is a little interesting. There is probably a simple solution, but although I have been searching the internet for a while, I haven't found a solution yet.

Here is the thing;

Let's say I am at the About page of my project. I used my toggle switches and now some of my elements and some sub components are displaying in the `About.vue`. Then I go and visit my `Services.vue` page and showing and hiding some elements and sub components as well. By the way, almost all of these pages have forms and I save these forms to local storage. When I return to My About page from my Services page, I see that the elements I activated have been restored. In other words, each component welcomes me with its default state when it is returned from another component. What I want to see is, If I go and check some checkboxes to show some element, No matter how long I roam between other routes, I want those elements to remain visible or hidden when I come back. For example, a toggle element must be activated to write a username and password on a component. After activating the toggle element, the user types the username and password and clicks the Save button. Then he continues to browse many areas of the project and when he returns, he sees that the toggle element is inactive and the username and password are not entered. I don't want it to be that way. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use vuex for solved this problem.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion. It also integrates with Vue's official devtools extension (opens new window)to provide advanced features such as zero-config time-travel debugging and state snapshot export / import.

Comment: store data with: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store and use computed and getters in your component look: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this without using Vuex? Some of my projects are not allowed to use any external npm packages...

Comment: @YasinDemirkaya yes you can use localStorage.setItem('key', 'value') and localStorage.getItem('key')

Comment: And how do I do that? Can you explain a little bit...